# Calling global.R in an app.R file on shiny server; unable to call dataframes in for global use

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I am developing a shiny app which is an exploratory data analysis tool. At this point, I am trying to optimise so that data is loaded in once but is readily available for all users. I am aware of the scoping materials on this i.e. [Scoping](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html) I have the code to load the data in for the app within a `global.R` file like so:-

```
#global.R file
library(feather)

dataframe1<-read_feather("df1.feather")
dataframe2<-read_feather("df2.feather")
```

These are the dataframes that I need to call once and make available to all users of the app. However, I am calling the `ui` and the `server` code all within `app.R` and I have a hunch that this could be problematic.

I have tried a few implementations as guided by what I have been able to see on the web but it is obvious that I am not doing something properly. Here are some examples of what I have tried

```
source('global.R', local = T)

ui<-fluidPage({

#code for ui

})

server<-function(input,output,server){

# code for server
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Where the outcome is this:-

[image]

The second thing I have tried is having the global file called in `onStart` parameter in the `shinyApp()`, but I have the same error.

The global file is saved in the GitLab repo that I am using to deploy this app on shiny server. The `app.R` script Can any one show me how I can correctly call the `global.R` file, so that the data is loaded in once and made available to all users of the app? Do I need to split the `app.R` file into a `ui.R` and a `server.R` file?

Comment: Using `app.R` aims at providing a single file application. Accordingly also your global variables can be placed in `app.R`. `global.R` is part of the multi file approach (server.R and ui.R) and is sourced automatically. However, your above code sourcing `global.R` from `app.R` should work. Are you sure this is your issue? What is written to the log files? Also see [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/app-formats.html).